# How can I open a website in my application so that Google Play accepts it?

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-play

I made a primitive application. When you start it on your phone, a website is opened. Here's how it looks in the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:Myapp.Views"
            x:Class="Myapp.Views.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView Source="Here_is_my_website.com"
                HeightRequest="1000"
                WidthRequest="1000" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

I sent my application via the Google Play console to the moderation and received the following response:

> Issue: Violation of Device and Network Abuse policy and section 4.9 of the Developer Distribution Agreement
>
> We don’t allow apps that interfere with, disrupt, damage, or access in an unauthorized manner the user’s device, other devices or computers, servers, networks, application programming interfaces (APIs), or services, including but not limited to other apps on the device, any Google service, or an authorized carrier’s network.

Why did this happen? What do I have to change so that my application can be hosted on Google Play?

Comment: You really need to contact Google and ask them for specifics about what you are doing wrong

Comment: 1: why do you need an app for opening a website? 2: you need to ask user permission to acces certain things on your app

Comment: @FabriBertani The fact is that I do not know how to program. But I also want traffic from Google Play :) I added this "<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />" to the AndrodManifest.hml file and sent the application for re-validation in google play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 4.9 You will not engage in any activity with Google Play, including making Your Products available via Google Play, that interferes with,
>   disrupts, damages or accesses in an unauthorised manner the devices,
>   servers, networks or other properties or services of any third party
>   including, but not limited to, Google or any Authorised Provider. You
>   may not use user information obtained via Google Play to sell or
>   distribute Products outside of Google Play.

For more info check: [developer-distribution-agreement](https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html)

I think that because you're using webview, you need to add an authorization to use the internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

The problem with Google is that they don't tell you the exact cause of the problem. You need to find it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The best place to get information about Google Play policy is [the Developer Policy center](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy/)

I'd guess you are falling foul of [the webspam rule](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/webviews-affiliate/)

Comment: [webspam rule](https://play.google.com/about/spam-min-functionality/spam/webviews-affiliate/) maybe the moderators think so. But this is really my site. There are no ads and affiliate links on my site. How can moderators prove that this is my site?

Comment: It might be falling foul of "We don't allow apps that spam users or Google Play, such as apps that send users unsolicited messages or apps that are repetitive or low-quality." It sounds like your app doesn't do anything so is low quality